# What user does SVN use to access files on Debian? (no repository found in ...)

Tags: debian, svn, repository, svn-server

I am setting up SVN on my Debian server, trying to get it to run through svnserve and not through WebDAV/Apache.

As root ...

I set up the base directory:

```
mkdir /var/svn
```

I first create the repository (named "base"):

```
svnadmin create /var/svn/base
```

I then edit the config file accordingly, allowing only authorised users. Next i edit the password file and add my user.

Locally, then, using my SVN client i try to connect to the repository. The connection succeeds but i then get an error message

```
No repository found in svn://myhost/base
```

I tried

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/svn
```

But to no avail.

Any help would be great! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you started svnserve here but my guess would be that you're not passing  the `-r` option.  `svnserve -d -r /var/svn` should do the trick.  If you don't specify `-r` then the root is the root `/` of your system (e.g. `svn://myhost/var/svn/base` would probably work)